# Mongoose consumes a lot memory when I use find().cursor()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node.js and Mongoose to query data from a mongodb (version 3.2):

```
let cursor = cbo.find({ 
    InsertTime: { 
        $gte: data.ValidTimeStart, 
        $lte: data.ValidTimeEnd 
    }
}).lean().cursor({batchSize:1000});

cursor.on('data', (chunk) => console.log(chunk));
cursor.on('end', () => console.log("end"));
```

The result is correct, but memory keeps going up until all results are returned and after a while it releases a lot memory. Normally I have around 1 million items, it takes almost 500 MB memory.

Would it be possible to use a cursor which returns a stream, to free some memory after every data emit.

How to use memory effectively?

Comment: So you got full data on `chunk`? that could lead to memory leak. use `cursor.next()` manually?

Comment: not full data on single chunk, every row enter chunk once . but the whole  find result will stay at memory not released until on end . I thought memory will release while on `chunk`

Comment: how did you solve this? @ttulka